# If my service consumes Kafka messages, can kafka somehow lose my offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

If I have a service that connects to kafka as a message consumer, and every message I read I send a commit to that message offset, so that if my service shutsdown and restarts it will start reading from the last read message onwards. My understanding is that the committed offset will be maintained by kafka.

Now my question is, do I have to worry about the offset? Can kafka somehow lose that information and when the service restarts start reading messages from the beginning of the topic or the end of it depending on my initial offset config? Or if kafka loses my offset it will also have lost all messages in the topic so that it is alright to read from the beginning?

Note: I use spring-kafka on the service, but not sure if that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases where you have an active consumer (with manual or auto-committing), you don't need to worry about it.

The cases where you do need to consider the behavior of `auto.offset.reset` setting is when the `offsets.retention.minutes` time on the broker has elapsed while your consumer group(s) are inactive. When this happens, Kafka compacts the `__consumer_offsets` topic and removes any offsets stored for those inactive groups

Losing offsets doesn't affect the source topic. Your client topic(s) have their own independent retention settings, and its message can be removed as well (or not), depending on how you've configured it.

Comment: So from what you are saying my only concern would be the offset retention time relative to my inactive time, so that I don't go inactive to the point of kafka discarding my offset and the application having to read messages it already processed before.

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of

Comment: The default is to purge the offsets one week after the last consumer left the group (this was a change in the 2.0/2.1 timeframe; it used to expire after the retention config even if the consumer was active but received no data for that time).

Comment: @GaryRussell Right. By "active", I mean actively committing offsets, rather than only actively consuming.

Comment: Right. I just wanted to emphasize that, with modern brokers, even an inactive, but connected, consumer will prevent the offsets from being expired. That used to not be the case.